# python: name a list based on the value of a variable

Tags: python

In perl, if I have a variable called $x with a value of "purple", I can easily create an array called @purple like this:

```
$x = 'purple';
@$x = ();
```

How can I do the equivalent in python by creating a list or dictionary based on the value of a variable?

Comment: We can, but we shouldn't. We use `use strict;` or equivalent to prevent ourselves from doing this nasty thing.